# How to read super large excel file using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file with over 1 million rows (about 60 MB) and I want to read them using java , I have the following code to read :

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
                new File(
                        "path/file.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

at creating workbook line it takes forever I tried it on small files it work perfectly but with this file it takes more than an hour and nothing !

what is the best way to read file like this ?

Comment: what do you do with the excel file? is it a simple csv type for or something complex? if it's simple you might not want/need the overhead invovled using the apache-poi library. Whats the context?

Comment: @raz_muh_taz I'm reading the excel file row by row and adding it to database

Comment: what does the row look like? is it a key:value pair? csv? whats the structure? why did you decide to use apache-poi library?

Comment: @raz_muh_taz I'm new to this and I don't know what is my structure but the file format is xlsx and contains normal data , how to know what is my structure ?

Comment: open the file in a normal text editor

Comment: @raz_muh_taz It can't be opend via text editor

Comment: are you constantly adding to the db each time you read a line? or do you create a statement that adds all the values when your done reading the file? if you add to the db per line, perhaps the insert into the db one row at a time is connecting to the db, adding the value, disconnecting. doing that over and over will cause some serious overhead

Comment: @raz_muh_taz I don't know why you care about what I'm going to do after reading is it important ? because I have the same file with same format but 20,000 rows and it works good but this file take long time creating workbook

Comment: like i mentioned earlier, depending on what you do per line could determine whether or not it scales well. For smaller files it will work fine but as soon as you scale up the file it takes forever. so clearly there is a scalability problem with your code which is dependent upon the file you read in.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz thank you

Comment: Why aren't you [following the instructions in the Apache POI docs for `If memory footprint is an issue, then for XSSF.....`](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)?